# Issue Submitting a Python Application to Yarn From Java Code

Tags: java, python, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am currently using Java (and the Yarn Client) to submit jobs to a yarn cluster (in a Ubunutu/Linux) environment.  When submitting Java programs, everything works just fine.  When submitting a Python program it seems to stall in the ACCEPTED state and eventually errors out.

Here is the code that I am using to submit the program:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * This class submits a SparkPi to a YARN from a Java client (as opposed 
 * to submitting a Spark job from a shell command line using spark-submit).
 * 
 * To accomplish submitting a Spark job from a Java client, we use 
 * the org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client class described below:
 * 
 Usage: org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client [options]
 Options:
  --jar JAR_PATH           Path to your application's JAR file (required in yarn-cluster mode)
  --class CLASS_NAME       Name of your application's main class (required)
  --primary-py-file        A main Python file
  --arg ARG                Argument to be passed to your application's main class. 
                   Multiple invocations are possible, each will be passed in order.
  --num-executors NUM      Number of executors to start (Default: 2)
  --executor-cores NUM     Number of cores per executor (Default: 1).
  --driver-memory MEM      Memory for driver (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 512 Mb)
  --driver-cores NUM       Number of cores used by the driver (Default: 1).
  --executor-memory MEM    Memory per executor (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1G)
  --name NAME              The name of your application (Default: Spark)
  --queue QUEUE            The hadoop queue to use for allocation requests (Default: 'default')
  --addJars jars           Comma separated list of local jars that want SparkContext.addJar to work with.
  --py-files PY_FILES      Comma-separated list of .zip, .egg, or .py files to place on the PYTHONPATH for Python apps.
  --files files            Comma separated list of files to be distributed with the job.
  --archives archives      Comma separated list of archives to be distributed with the job.

  How to call this program example:

     export SPARK_HOME="/opt/spark/spark-1.6.0"
     java -DSPARK_HOME="$SPARK_HOME" org.dataalgorithms.client.SubmitYARNJobFromJava 10
*/
public class SubmitPyYARNJobFromJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // this is passed to SparkPi program
    String slices = args[0];  
    // String slices = "15";


    // String SPARK_HOME = System.getProperty("SPARK_HOME");
    String SPARK_HOME = "/opt/spark/spark-1.6.0";

    //
    pi(SPARK_HOME, slices); // ... the code being measured ... 
    //
    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    }

    static void pi(String SPARK_HOME, String slices) throws Exception {
    //       
    String[] args = new String[]{
        // application name
        "--name",
        "SparkPi-Python",

        // Python Program
        "--primary-py-file",
        SPARK_HOME + "/examples/src/main/python/pi.py",

        // number of executors
        "--num-executors",  
        "2",

        // driver memory
        "--driver-memory",
        "512m",

        // executor memory
        "--executor-memory", 
        "512m",

        // executor cores
        "--executor-cores", 
        "2",

        // argument 1 to my Spark program
        "--arg",
        slices,

        // argument 2 to my Spark program (helper argument to create a proper JavaSparkContext object)
        "--arg",
        "yarn-cluster"
    };

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    //
    System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");
    //
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
    ClientArguments clientArgs = new ClientArguments(args, sparkConf);
    Client client = new Client(clientArgs, config, sparkConf);

    client.run();
    // done!
    }
}
```

I am invoking the code from the command line as follows:

```
java -cp *:. SubmitPyYARNJobFromJava 10
```

The Pi.py program is the standard program that comes with Spark-1.6.0 built for Hadoop-2.6.0.

```
from __future__ import print_function
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

import sys
from random import random
from operator import add

from pyspark import SparkContext


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Usage: pi [partitions]
    """
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonPi")
    partitions = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 2
    n = 100000 * partitions

    def f(_):
    x = random() * 2 - 1
    y = random() * 2 - 1
    return 1 if x ** 2 + y ** 2 < 1 else 0

    count = sc.parallelize(range(1, n + 1), partitions).map(f).reduce(add)
    print("Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / n))

    sc.stop()
```

When the job is submitted, it appears like it's going to be submitted correctly.  It gets to the accepted state and then it stalls.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/02/12 16:15:24 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
16/02/12 16:15:24 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (2048 MB per container)
16/02/12 16:15:24 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
16/02/12 16:15:24 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
16/02/12 16:15:24 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
16/02/12 16:15:24 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
16/02/12 16:15:25 INFO Client: Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying file:/home/shunley/workspace/rabbitmq_java_rpc/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar
16/02/12 16:15:25 INFO Client: Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying file:/tmp/spark-7dbbb73f-e5bc-4fc1-a535-02a60cb68b16/__spark_conf__6244658246692860568.zip
16/02/12 16:15:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: shunley
16/02/12 16:15:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: shunley
16/02/12 16:15:25 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(shunley); users with modify permissions: Set(shunley)
16/02/12 16:15:26 INFO Client: Submitting application 8 to ResourceManager
16/02/12 16:15:26 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1455307995259_0008
16/02/12 16:15:27 INFO Client: Application report for application_1455307995259_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/12 16:15:27 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1455311726233
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://shunley-VirtualBox:8088/proxy/application_1455307995259_0008/
     user: shunley
16/02/12 16:15:28 INFO Client: Application report for application_1455307995259_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/12 16:15:29 INFO Client: Application report for application_1455307995259_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/12 16:15:30 INFO Client: Application report for application_1455307995259_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/12 16:15:31 INFO Client: Application report for application_1455307995259_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/12 16:15:32 INFO Client: Application report for application_1455307995259_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/12 16:15:33 INFO Client: Application report for application_1455307995259_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/12 16:15:34 INFO Client: Application report for application_1455307995259_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
```

Then it finally FAILS and the error that is given is the following:

```
16/02/12 16:43:56 INFO Client: Application report for application_1455307995259_0009 (state: FAILED)
16/02/12 16:43:56 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1455307995259_0009 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1455307995259_0009_000002 exited with  exitCode: 10
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://shunley-VirtualBox:8088/proxy/application_1455307995259_0009/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1455307995259_0009_02_000001
Exit code: 10
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=10: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 10
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1455313224060
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://shunley-VirtualBox:8088/cluster/app/application_1455307995259_0009
     user: shunley
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1455307995259_0009 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1029)
    at SubmitPyYARNJobFromJava.pi(SubmitPyYARNJobFromJava.java:101)
    at SubmitPyYARNJobFromJava.main(SubmitPyYARNJobFromJava.java:52)
16/02/12 16:43:56 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/02/12 16:43:56 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-f5f15d4f-7383-4a97-b2ff-5734148d8a29
```

I have tried searching everywhere on google for anything like this, but to no avail.  Has anyone seen anything like this before?  I need to be able to submit python and java applications to Yarn via code.  So far, Python is the only one that is not working.  I can submit Java and Scala (haven't tried R yet), but Python, which is what our Data Scientists are using for Machine Learning, is not working.

Any help or pointers to help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Client argument missed "--class" and "--py-files".

For submitting python scripts, the class should be "org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner."
Besides, pyspark library and py4j should also be attached so that driver could import spark properly.

Thus you client config should look like below:

```
String[] args = new String[]{
    // application name
    "--name",
    "SparkPi-Python",

    "--class",
    "org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner",

    "--py-files",
    SPARK_HOME + "/python/lib/pyspark.zip,"+ SPARK_HOME +"/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip",

    // Python Program
    "--primary-py-file",
    SPARK_HOME + "/examples/src/main/python/pi.py",

    // number of executors
    "--num-executors",  
    "2",

    // driver memory
    "--driver-memory",
    "512m",

    // executor memory
    "--executor-memory", 
    "512m",

    // executor cores
    "--executor-cores", 
    "2",

    // argument 1 to my Spark program
    "--arg",
    slices,

    // argument 2 to my Spark program (helper argument to create a proper JavaSparkContext object)
    "--arg",
    "yarn-cluster"
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the --class that opened up an avenue to a solution where we are able to handle all of this in python without needed the java client!

Answer (score 0):

was anything meningful printed to STDERR? check by running yarn log -applicationId appid

oozie now supports spark action, perhaps you could try using oozie rather then writing your own submitter.

Comment: Well, the stdout had basically the same output as the console.  I am looking at Hue and the Livy Server to use for job submission.  From looking at the code it appears that there is an issue handing off to pyspark from my java client.  It executes Scala and Java (jars) ok as they are running through the JVM?  But python and R have their own environments that need to be invoked?

Comment: Well, in the end I gave up on submitting python jobs to YARN from Java code.  It was much easier to use Livy-Server to make RESTful job submissions for Python, Java, Scala and R.

Scott